# Why the marginal contribution of a feature is the difference between the feature effect minus the average effect

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, shap, feature-importances

In several sources the **marginal contribution** is defined as

> the difference between the prediction with and without the feature.

However, recently I read an article where the marginal contribution was defined as the:

> difference between the feature effect minus the average effect.

Suppose a linear model:

```
fˆ(x) = β0 + β1x1 + … + βpxp
```

which is what a model prediction looks like for **one data instance**.

where **x** is the instance for which we want to compute the contributions. Each xj is a feature value, with **j = 1,…,p**.

The **βj** is the weight corresponding to feature **j**.

Therefore, the marginal contribution of feature **j** in the model **fˆ** is:

```
ϕj(fˆ)=βjxj − E(βjXj)
```

where **E( β j X j )** is the mean effect estimate for feature j.

I am having difficulty to understand this definition. I would like to know where this definition come from and how it relates with the other definition:

> marginal contribution is the difference between the prediction with
> and without the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crucial [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/catav21a/catav21a.pdf) to be read that I was also unaware of.$^\dagger$ The article points out the essential differences, both from a theoretical and empirical point of view, between feature importance scores that explain the *model* and those that explain the *data*.

Your first definition reflects the importance of a feature for a single prediction (i.e., *local*), while the second reflects the (entire) model's performance (i.e., *global*).

---

<sup><sub>$^\dagger$ Thank you for that.</sub></sup>